# How prevent Sharepoint add new list item limit more than 5, not View items

Tags: sharepoint

Share Point add list item count greater than 5 show validation, is it possible with validation. If not please let me know the process.

Answer (score 0):

We can use REST API to get items count by the current user, then prevent new item in new form page.

Example, add the code below into script editor web part in newform.aspx page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listTitle="CL0902";
$(function () {         
    var itemCount=getItemsCountByAuthor(listTitle);
    if(itemCount >= 5){
        alert("You can not add item more than 5.");
        window.location.href=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/lists/"+listTitle+"/AllItems.aspx";
    }
});
function PreSaveItem(){
    var itemCount=getItemsCountByAuthor(listTitle);
    if(itemCount >= 5){
        alert("You can not add item more than 5.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function getItemsCountByAuthor(listTitle){
    var itemCount=0;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listTitle+"')/items?$select=Author/ID,ID&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/Id eq "+_spPageContextInfo.userId,
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            itemCount=data.d.results.length;        
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return itemCount;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can i write above code into direct list/mylist/newform.aspx? Unable to insert newform in web parts. I dont know what happening

Comment: Did you use the modern list form? In classic list form, we can edit the page and add script editor web part to the page.

Comment: Actually i have taken code from Newform.aspx in mylist and then create one custom page in pages then cooy that code into new page with name spaces. I tried to validation using json formula and colum validation but not reached my expectations for column validation using some thing like this. But this is date based https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePointListItemsLimit.htm

Comment: If you use the custom new form page, we need monitor the "Save" button click event, then call the method getItemsCountByAuthor to validate.